# Error Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row when get row product review

Tags: magento2, php, database

Show error when get review product like this:

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

what's wrong about this query ?

```
SELECT a.created_at,a.entity_pk_value,b.title,b.detail,b.nickname,d.percent,d.value,(
    SELECT b.value FROM eav_attribute a
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar b ON b.attribute_id=a.attribute_id
    WHERE attribute_code='name' AND entity_id=a.entity_pk_value
) AS name FROM review a
INNER JOIN review_detail b on b.review_id=a.review_id
INNER JOIN rating_option_vote d on d.review_id=a.review_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.entity_id FROM eav_attribute a
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int b ON b.attribute_id=a.attribute_id
    WHERE attribute_code='udropship_vendor' AND value=$id
)c on c.entity_id=a.entity_pk_value
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.entity_id,b.value FROM eav_attribute a
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int b ON b.attribute_id=a.attribute_id
    WHERE attribute_code='status'
)e on e.entity_id=a.entity_pk_value
WHERE a.status_id=1 AND e.value=1
ORDER BY a.created_at DESC
```

So, this query run in graphql get the review product by 'udropship_vendor', What do you think would allow duplicated data in that subquery to produce such an error?